# Finding driving directions using google in iOS, Android and Windows Phone app

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, windows-phone-8, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a iOS, Android and Windows Phone app, all in native language. Atm I'm calculating distance between current location and a list of points. Here's a sample on how i do this on Android:

```
Location currentLocation = new Location( "CurrentLocation" );
Location.distanceBetween(mLatitude, mLongitude, tempLoc.getLatitude(), tempLoc.getLongitude(), results);
```

Problem is that Location.distanceBetween gives me a distance in birds eyes, i would like to change this to give me the distance for driving directions(fastest route)(only need the distance, not drawing it out on a map). I'm not even sure if this is possible. So i got 2 questions.

1. Is this even possible with google API?
2. If yes, what options do i have(keep in mind that developing for 3 platforms)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask Google API for the driving route between those two points, and iterate over each step, which includes the distance.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON

For example, you could do a request like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&sensor=false
```

but using coordinates instead of addresses. The result would be something like this:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "routes": [ {
    "summary": "I-40 W",
    "legs": [ {
      "steps": [ {
        "travel_mode": "DRIVING",
        "start_location": {
          "lat": 41.8507300,
          "lng": -87.6512600
        },
        "end_location": {
          "lat": 41.8525800,
          "lng": -87.6514100
        },
        "polyline": {
          "points": "a~l~Fjk~uOwHJy@P"
        },
        "duration": {
          "value": 19,
          "text": "1 min"
        },
        "html_instructions": "Head \u003cb\u003enorth\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eS Morgan St\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eW Cermak Rd\u003c/b\u003e",
        "distance": {
          "value": 207,
          "text": "0.1 mi"
        }
      },...
```

Maybe you could add the **distance value** of each step: 207 + ...